# iOS AVPlayer Play/Pause button issue

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am using `AVPlayer` to play a live stream from the Internet using the following code :

```
    NSString *u = @"http://192.192.192.192:8036";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:u];
radiosound = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [radiosound play];
```

And I have one button play :

```
[radiosound play];
```

and Pause :

```
[radiosound pause];
```

My issue is that I want to use only one button Play/Pause, but when I am using this code

```
if (radiosound.isPlaying) {         
    [radiosound pause]; 
} else {                
     [radiosound play]; 
}
```

My app crashes, because AVPlayer doesn´t recognize "isPlaying".

Any tips?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`AVPlayer` doesn't have an `isPlaying` property. Use the `rate` property (0.0 means stopped, 1.0 playing).

```
if (radiosound.rate == 1.0) {         
    [radiosound pause]; 
} else {                
     [radiosound play]; 
}
```

You can look at the `AVPlayer` class reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayer/rate).

Comment: Some people say it will still be 1.0 in airplane mode even if paused.

Comment: Probably it's not a good idea to compare _float_ with _1.0_. Maybe __if (radiosound.rate > 0.99)__?

Comment: @SoftDesigner good point, but AFAICT both 0.0 and 1.0 are both precisely representable in [IEEE-754 floating point](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/floating_point/understanding_floating_point_representation.html).

Comment: you can user timeControlStatus property of AVPlayer. 
`player.timeControlStatus == .paused
player.timeControlStatus == .playing`

Answer (score 5):

After some research I found out that when there is no network connection, `AVPlayer` still sets the rate to 1.0 after receiving a `-play` message.

Thus, I also check for the currentItem and modified my method like that:

```
-(BOOL)isPlaying
{
    if (self.player.currentItem && self.player.rate != 0)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Please share your opinion if you think something is wrong with this approach.

Comment: What is the point of checking for currentItem? Upon pause it should not be nil. The item doesn't go away just because you pause the player.